quantlib and bbg fixed coupon bond analytics do not match
We are trying to match analytics like ytm, duration and convexity iven Bloomberg Price as an input. For most bonds, quantlib and bbg fixed bond analytics match. But for very few bonds ytm matches but not duration and convexity.

Examaple CUSIP 66977WAP4
Day count Using 30/360
Price of Bond on Bloomberg: 99.704 on 11/18/2024 . This is the same date Quantlib generated numbers
Start Date: Oct 28 2014 ; End Date: May 1 2025; Coupon : 5%;
Calendar ql.UnitedStates.Settlement . Where do I see this on bbg terminal ?
Mismatch results yld_ytm_mid matches to 5.700 but bbg vs QL
duration is 0.451 vs 0.4527 and convexity is 0.004 vs 0.0038.

Question


Why a mismatch ?
Will dump of all fields using {FLDS} or //blp/apiflds help ?


BBG 0.004 could very easily be 0.0038 rounded

Additionally you havent provided any of the fundamental details to actually verify those values.

@Attack68

Will a dump of {FLDS} or //blp/apiflds narrow a problem ?


I see some of your values in BBG and not all.

If I replicate this in rateslib with the following calculation conventions I get:
from rateslib import *  # Python 3.12, rateslib 1.5.0
from rateslib.instruments.bonds import BondCalcMode

print("Accrual: YTM Accrual: v1: YTM: Mod Duration: Convexity")

for v1_type in ["compounding", "compounding_final_simple"]:
    mode = BondCalcMode(
        settle_accrual_type="30e360",
        ytm_accrual_type="30e360",
        v1_type=v1_type,
        v2_type="regular",
        v3_type="simple"
    )

    frb = FixedRateBond(
        effective=dt(2014, 10, 28),
        termination=dt(2025, 5, 1),
        fixed_rate=5.0,
        frequency="S",
        calendar="nyc",
        modifier="none",
        convention="30360",
        calc_mode=mode
    )
    ytm = frb.ytm(price=99.704, settlement=dt(2024, 11, 18))
    dur = frb.duration(ytm=ytm, settlement=dt(2024, 11, 18), metric="modified")
    conv = frb.convexity(ytm=ytm, settlement=dt(2024, 11, 18))
    print(f"{v1_type}:{ytm:.5f}:{dur:.5f}:{conv:.5f}")

Then I return the following values:
v1_type:                  YTM:     Mod Duration: Convexity
compounding:              5.66463: 0.44031:      0.00408
compounding_final_simple: 5.65713: 0.44147:      0.00390

In my experience if you replicate the right conventions in Quantlib you also get the same values. But there are often many different types of bond conventions that you need to match specifically.

@Attach68 can you please show the following when you do {FLDS} on terminal. yld_ytm_xxx dur_xxx dur_adj_xxx cnvx_xxx . Please replace xxx with bid ask mid . My valyes from Nov 18 will be somewhere. I can regenerate mine for Nov 19th after your reply

no, because the above is sufficient to evidence bbg working with this bond.its also all statically computed given a specific price and settlement.
